# How to generalise my excel-macro to work from Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to vba. This is a test macro to open access and close a workbook. I am using Excel 2007 on Win 7 & Win XP

This works fine but I can only place the result in the WorkSheet that contains the macro. To try and make it reusable I used the commented code line and also placed the macro in a Personal.xlsb file. I get a Subscript Out of range error. I would appreciate any help?

```
Sub copyCount()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fname As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    fname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Deepak\Documents\OFFICE\FixedValues.xlsx", True, True)
     'With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fname)
        .Range("A1").Value = wb.Worksheets("common").Range("A1").Value
    End With
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you Cross Posted this question in Ozgrid or any other forum as well? If yes, please mention all the links in your question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Rereading your question again, I misunderstood at first. Try this code instead in your Personal workbook. The ActiveWorkbook in your commented code becomes the file you opened, that's why it wouldn't work. You need to set both workbooks as variables.

```
Sub copyCount()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim fname As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
fname = wb1.Name
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Deepak\Documents\OFFICE\FixedValues.xlsx", True, True)
With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fname)
    .Range("A1") = wb2.Worksheets("common").Range("A1")
End With
wb2.Close False
Set wb2 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Unrelated but fun info: you don't actually need to add .Value at the end of the ranges since this is the default property that's used. I removed it above.